# JSON + jQuery - Filtering Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I hate to bother you all, but I cannot get my filters functioning. I've posted the code I'm working on below without any of my attempts in there (the dropdown menu and checkboxes have no functions assigned to them) to make things slightly easier to see.

I want the user to be able to click the checkboxes and select countries from a dropdown on the left that will filter all of the results.

I want the dropdown to populate automatically with unique country fields (field.COUNTRY). This is a problem within the problem - I tried jQuery.unique and .filter on the country list, and then .filter actions via jQuery on the data field results.

Basically, I'm probably just too fried to see what I'm doing wrong, but maybe one of you smart peoples can see a solution through my messy code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7g9yf.json", function(data){
          
            $.each(data, function(i, field){
              var name = field.NAME;
              var url = field.URL;
              var customs = field.CUSTOMS;
              var ones = field.ONE_OFFS;
              var originals = field.ORIGINAL_MODELS;
              var order = field.ORDER_ONLINE;
              var city = field.CITY;
              var state = field.STATE;
              var country = field.COUNTRY;
              var luthier = field.LUTHIER;
              var email = field.EMAIL;
              var tel = field.TEL;
              var store = field.STORE;
              var info = field.INFO;
              var specialty = field.SPECIALTY;
              var school = field.SCHOOL;
                $("#show-data").append("<div class='LD_item_wrap'>  <div class='LD_1'><h3>" + name + "</h3></div><div class='LD_2'>" + "<a class='LD_lnk' rel='nofollow' href='" + url + "'" + "target='_blank'>" + url + "</a>" + "</div>  <div class='LD_lctn'><div class='LD_7'>" + city + "</div><div class='LD_8'>" + state + "</div><div class='LD_9'>" + country + "</div>  </div><div class='LD_3'>Custom Builds?<span>" + customs + "</span></div><div class='LD_4'>One-Offs?<span>" + ones + "</span></div><div class='LD_5'>Original Models?<span>" + originals + "</span></div><div class='LD_6'>Order Online?<span>" + order + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_cntct_div'>Contact Details</div>  <div class='LD_cnt_cnt'>  <div class='LD_10'><sup>Luthier</sup><span>" + luthier + "</span></div>    <div class='LD_11'><sup>Email</sup><span>" + "<a class='LD_MF' href='mailto:" + email + "' target='_top'>" + email + "</a></span>" + "</div><div class='LD_12'><sup>Tel</sup><span>" + tel + "</span></div> <div class='LD_13'><sup>Shop</sup><span>" + store + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_14'><sup>Info</sup><span>" + info + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_15'><sup>Specialty</sup><span>" + specialty + "</span></div><div class='LD_16'><sup>School/Course</sup><span>" + school + "</span></div></div></div>");
        });
          $('.LD_MF').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.attr('href', that.attr('href').replace('[x.x]', '.').replace('[x..x]', '@'));
  that.html(that.html().replace('[x.x]', '.').replace('[x..x]', '@'));
});

var check = $('.LD_item_wrap div');
for (var i = 0; i <= check.length; i++) {
       if ($(check[i]).text() == '') {
             $(check[i]).css('display','none');
          }
     }

          
var check3 = $('.LD_item_wrap div span');
var check2 = check3.parent();
for (var i = 0; i <= check3.length; i++) {
       if ($(check3[i]).text() == '') {
             $(check2[i]).css('display','none');
          }
     }

var yn = $('.LD_item_wrap div span');
for (var i = 0; i <= yn.length; i++) {
       if ($(yn[i]).text() == 'Yes') {
             $(yn[i]).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px" height="15px"><g><g><polygon points="293.333,135.04 190.08,240.213 137.173,187.093 108.8,215.467 192.213,298.667 326.187,168.747   " fill="#91DC5A"/></g></g><g><g><path d="M213.333,0C95.513,0,0,95.513,0,213.333s95.513,213.333,213.333,213.333s213.333-95.513,213.333-213.333    S331.154,0,213.333,0z M213.333,388.053c-96.495,0-174.72-78.225-174.72-174.72s78.225-174.72,174.72-174.72    c96.446,0.117,174.602,78.273,174.72,174.72C388.053,309.829,309.829,388.053,213.333,388.053z" fill="#91DC5A"/></g></g></svg>');
          }
     }

for (var i = 0; i <= yn.length; i++) {
       if ($(yn[i]).text() == 'No') {
             $(yn[i]).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px" height="15px"><g><g><polygon points="303.147,153.813 272.853,123.52 213.333,183.253 153.813,123.52 123.52,153.813 183.253,213.333 123.52,272.853     153.813,303.147 213.333,243.413 272.853,303.147 303.147,272.853 243.413,213.333   " fill="#D80027"/></g></g><g><g><path d="M213.333,0C95.513,0,0,95.513,0,213.333s95.513,213.333,213.333,213.333s213.333-95.513,213.333-213.333    S331.154,0,213.333,0z M213.333,388.053c-96.495,0-174.72-78.225-174.72-174.72s78.225-174.72,174.72-174.72    c96.446,0.117,174.602,78.273,174.72,174.72C388.053,309.829,309.829,388.053,213.333,388.053z" fill="#D80027"/></g></g></svg>');
          }
     }

          $('.LD_14').hide();
    });
  
  });
```

```css
body {margin:0; padding:10px 0;}
/* Testing JSON Data Manipulation */
#LDWrap {border:1px #666 solid; width:600px; height:420px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:0; border-radius:20px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc; font-family:Lato; color:#666;}
#LDX {width:600px; height:50px; text-align:center;}
#LDX h2 {font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:0; margin:0; line-height:50px;}
#LDX h2 span {color:#cc4c4c;}
#LDMen {width:120px; height:400px; float:left;}
#LDInf {width:480px; height:400px; float:left;}
#LD_scrl {width:100%; text-align:center; line-height:20px;font-size:12px;color:#ccc;}
#LD_filters {font-size:10px;padding:4px;}
#LD_filters select {display:block;padding:0;margin:0 0 10px 0; outline:none;}
#LD_filters span {margin-left:6px;}
#LD_filters > * {display:inline-block;margin:4px 0; line-height:10px;}

#LDMen h4 {color:#cc4c4c;text-align:center;}
#show-data {height:calc(100% - 80px); overflow:scroll; margin:10px; padding:5px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc inset;}





.LD_item_wrap a {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
.LD_item_wrap a:hover {color:#cc4c4c;}
.LD_item_wrap a:active {color:#fff;}
.LD_item_wrap {margin:20px auto; width:calc(100% - 12px); height:auto;border:1px #ccc dotted;padding:5px;}
.LD_item_wrap div {margin:0;padding:0; line-height:20px;}
.LD_item_wrap div span svg {padding-right:10px; float:right;}
.LD_cntct_div {width:100%; border-bottom:1px #ccc dotted;margin:10px 0px 5px 0px !important; color:#ccc; font-size:12px; text-align:center;}
.LD_cnt_cnt {text-align:center;}
.LD_cnt_cnt sup {float:left;font-size:9px;line-height:20px;text-transform:uppercase;}

.LD_1 {text-align:center;}
.LD_1 h3 {font-weight:bold; margin:0; color:#cc4c4c;}
.LD_2 {font-size:12px; text-align:center;}
.LD_lctn {text-align:center; font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom:3px !important; font-weight:bold;}
.LD_7 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_7:after {content:'•';padding:0 4px;}
.LD_8 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_8:after {content:'•';padding:0 4px;}
.LD_9 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_3 {}
.LD_4 {}
.LD_5 {}
.LD_6 {}
.LD_10 {}
.LD_11 {font-size:12px;}
.LD_12 {}
.LD_13 {}
.LD_14 {}
.LD_15 {}
.LD_16 {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LDWrap">
  <div id="LDX"><h2>Custom Guitar Builders <span>Directory</span></h2></div>
  <div id="LDMen">
    <h4>Filter Results</h4>
<div id="LD_filters">
  <span>Country:</span>
  <select>
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
  <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filt_customs" value="customs"><span>Custom Builders</span><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="filt_originals" value="originals"><span>Original Models</span><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filt_orders" value="orders"><span>Online Orders</span><br>
    </div> <!---filters--->
  </div>
  <div id="LDInf">
    <div id="show-data"></div>
    <div id="LD_scrl">Scroll Down</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't have any change event listeners for the controls on left to do any filtering based on user events. Code shown only runs once .... when the page loads

Comment: Beyond that, not clear what your specific question really is

Comment: I can't get .filter / .unique to work on the JSON data that's loaded into the div on the right

Comment: Filter it based on what criteria and when? You need to break this down into bite sized chunks and be more specific. Can't eat an elephant all in one bite. Will get quick solid answers here when questions are clear and concise. Otherwise it's *"garbage in-> garbage out"*

Comment: Two people answered both my questions perfectly. Statistically, your ethos only applies to you - anything in -> garbage out. Helping people isn't your thing, carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updates:**

HTML: add this IDs to these inputs

```
<select id="countryFilter">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  //...
</select>
<input id="customsFilter" type="checkbox" name="filt_customs" value="customs">
<input id="originalsFilter" type="checkbox" name="filt_originals" value="originals">
<input id="orderFilter" type="checkbox" name="filt_orders" value="orders">
```

Javascript: Add an event listener to the inputs above. Add classes to `.LD_item_wrap` divs when creating them to serve for filtering.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Event listenr for the change event on all the input elements.
        $("#countryFilter, #customsFilter, #originalsFilter, #orderFilter").on("change", function() {
            // retrieving their value
            var country = $("#countryFilter").val().toLowerCase();
            var customs = $("#customsFilter").is(":checked");
            var originals = $("#originalsFilter").is(":checked");
            var order = $("#orderFilter").is(":checked");

            // generating a selector that will show only the element matching the criterias chosen by the user
            var selector = "";
            if (country != "all") selector += ".filter-country-" + country;
            if (customs) selector += ".filter-customs";
            if (originals) selector += ".filter-originals";
            if (order) selector += ".filter-order";

            if (selector.length == 0)
                selector = ".LD_item_wrap";
            else
                selector = ".LD_item_wrap" + selector;

            // hide all .LD_item_wrap elements
            $(".LD_item_wrap").hide();
            // and show only the selected ones
            $(selector).show();
        });

        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7g9yf.json", function(data){

            $.each(data, function(i, field) {
                var name = field.NAME;
                var url = field.URL;
                var customs = field.CUSTOMS;
                var ones = field.ONE_OFFS;
                var originals = field.ORIGINAL_MODELS;
                var order = field.ORDER_ONLINE;
                var city = field.CITY;
                var state = field.STATE;
                var country = field.COUNTRY;
                var luthier = field.LUTHIER;
                var email = field.EMAIL;
                var tel = field.TEL;
                var store = field.STORE;
                var info = field.INFO;
                var specialty = field.SPECIALTY;
                var school = field.SCHOOL;

                // generating the classes that will serve for filtering
                var classString = "filter-country-" + country.toLowerCase();
                if (customs == "Yes") classString += " filter-customs";
                if (originals == "Yes") classString += " filter-originals";
                if (order == "Yes") classString += " filter-order";

                // insert the classString into .LD_item_wrap div's class
                $("#show-data").append("<div class='LD_item_wrap " + classString + "'>  <div class='LD_1'><h3>" + name + "</...
```

**RESULT:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#countryFilter, #customsFilter, #originalsFilter, #orderFilter").on("change", function() {
            var country = $("#countryFilter").val().toLowerCase();
            var customs = $("#customsFilter").is(":checked");
            var originals = $("#originalsFilter").is(":checked");
            var order = $("#orderFilter").is(":checked");

            var selector = "";
            if (country != "all") selector += ".filter-country-" + country;
            if (customs) selector += ".filter-customs";
            if (originals) selector += ".filter-originals";
            if (order) selector += ".filter-order";

            if (selector.length == 0)
                selector = ".LD_item_wrap";
            else
                selector = ".LD_item_wrap" + selector;

            $(".LD_item_wrap").hide();
            $(selector).show();
        });

        $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7g9yf.json", function(data){

            $.each(data, function(i, field) {
                var name = field.NAME;
                var url = field.URL;
                var customs = field.CUSTOMS;
                var ones = field.ONE_OFFS;
                var originals = field.ORIGINAL_MODELS;
                var order = field.ORDER_ONLINE;
                var city = field.CITY;
                var state = field.STATE;
                var country = field.COUNTRY;
                var luthier = field.LUTHIER;
                var email = field.EMAIL;
                var tel = field.TEL;
                var store = field.STORE;
                var info = field.INFO;
                var specialty = field.SPECIALTY;
                var school = field.SCHOOL;

                var classString = "filter-country-" + country.toLowerCase();
                if (customs == "Yes") classString += " filter-customs";
                if (originals == "Yes") classString += " filter-originals";
                if (order == "Yes") classString += " filter-order";

                $("#show-data").append("<div class='LD_item_wrap " + classString + "'>  <div class='LD_1'><h3>" + name + "</h3></div><div class='LD_2'>" + "<a class='LD_lnk' rel='nofollow' href='" + url + "'" + "target='_blank'>" + url + "</a>" + "</div>  <div class='LD_lctn'><div class='LD_7'>" + city + "</div><div class='LD_8'>" + state + "</div><div class='LD_9'>" + country + "</div>  </div><div class='LD_3'>Custom Builds?<span>" + customs + "</span></div><div class='LD_4'>One-Offs?<span>" + ones + "</span></div><div class='LD_5'>Original Models?<span>" + originals + "</span></div><div class='LD_6'>Order Online?<span>" + order + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_cntct_div'>Contact Details</div>  <div class='LD_cnt_cnt'>  <div class='LD_10'><sup>Luthier</sup><span>" + luthier + "</span></div>    <div class='LD_11'><sup>Email</sup><span>" + "<a class='LD_MF' href='mailto:" + email + "' target='_top'>" + email + "</a></span>" + "</div><div class='LD_12'><sup>Tel</sup><span>" + tel + "</span></div> <div class='LD_13'><sup>Shop</sup><span>" + store + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_14'><sup>Info</sup><span>" + info + "</span></div>  <div class='LD_15'><sup>Specialty</sup><span>" + specialty + "</span></div><div class='LD_16'><sup>School/Course</sup><span>" + school + "</span></div></div></div>");
            });
            $('.LD_MF').each(function() {
                var that = $(this);
                that.attr('href', that.attr('href').replace('[x.x]', '.').replace('[x..x]', '@'));
                that.html(that.html().replace('[x.x]', '.').replace('[x..x]', '@'));
            });

            var check = $('.LD_item_wrap div');
            for (var i = 0; i <= check.length; i++) {
                if ($(check[i]).text() == '') {
                    $(check[i]).css('display', 'none');
                }
            }


            var check3 = $('.LD_item_wrap div span');
            var check2 = check3.parent();
            for (var i = 0; i <= check3.length; i++) {
                if ($(check3[i]).text() == '') {
                    $(check2[i]).css('display', 'none');
                }
            }

            var yn = $('.LD_item_wrap div span');
            for (var i = 0; i <= yn.length; i++) {
                if ($(yn[i]).text() == 'Yes') {
                    $(yn[i]).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px" height="15px"><g><g><polygon points="293.333,135.04 190.08,240.213 137.173,187.093 108.8,215.467 192.213,298.667 326.187,168.747   " fill="#91DC5A"/></g></g><g><g><path d="M213.333,0C95.513,0,0,95.513,0,213.333s95.513,213.333,213.333,213.333s213.333-95.513,213.333-213.333    S331.154,0,213.333,0z M213.333,388.053c-96.495,0-174.72-78.225-174.72-174.72s78.225-174.72,174.72-174.72    c96.446,0.117,174.602,78.273,174.72,174.72C388.053,309.829,309.829,388.053,213.333,388.053z" fill="#91DC5A"/></g></g></svg>');
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i <= yn.length; i++) {
                if ($(yn[i]).text() == 'No') {
                    $(yn[i]).html('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve" width="15px" height="15px"><g><g><polygon points="303.147,153.813 272.853,123.52 213.333,183.253 153.813,123.52 123.52,153.813 183.253,213.333 123.52,272.853     153.813,303.147 213.333,243.413 272.853,303.147 303.147,272.853 243.413,213.333   " fill="#D80027"/></g></g><g><g><path d="M213.333,0C95.513,0,0,95.513,0,213.333s95.513,213.333,213.333,213.333s213.333-95.513,213.333-213.333    S331.154,0,213.333,0z M213.333,388.053c-96.495,0-174.72-78.225-174.72-174.72s78.225-174.72,174.72-174.72    c96.446,0.117,174.602,78.273,174.72,174.72C388.053,309.829,309.829,388.053,213.333,388.053z" fill="#D80027"/></g></g></svg>');
                }
            }

            $('.LD_14').hide();
        });

    });
```

```css
body {margin:0; padding:10px 0;}
/* Testing JSON Data Manipulation */
#LDWrap {border:1px #666 solid; width:600px; height:420px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:0; border-radius:20px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc; font-family:Lato; color:#666;}
#LDX {width:600px; height:50px; text-align:center;}
#LDX h2 {font-size:20px; text-transform:uppercase; padding:0; margin:0; line-height:50px;}
#LDX h2 span {color:#cc4c4c;}
#LDMen {width:120px; height:400px; float:left;}
#LDInf {width:480px; height:400px; float:left;}
#LD_scrl {width:100%; text-align:center; line-height:20px;font-size:12px;color:#ccc;}
#LD_filters {font-size:10px;padding:4px;}
#LD_filters select {display:block;padding:0;margin:0 0 10px 0; outline:none;}
#LD_filters span {margin-left:6px;}
#LD_filters > * {display:inline-block;margin:4px 0; line-height:10px;}

#LDMen h4 {color:#cc4c4c;text-align:center;}
#show-data {height:calc(100% - 80px); overflow:scroll; margin:10px; padding:5px; box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #ccc inset;}





.LD_item_wrap a {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
.LD_item_wrap a:hover {color:#cc4c4c;}
.LD_item_wrap a:active {color:#fff;}
.LD_item_wrap {margin:20px auto; width:calc(100% - 12px); height:auto;border:1px #ccc dotted;padding:5px;}
.LD_item_wrap div {margin:0;padding:0; line-height:20px;}
.LD_item_wrap div span svg {padding-right:10px; float:right;}
.LD_cntct_div {width:100%; border-bottom:1px #ccc dotted;margin:10px 0px 5px 0px !important; color:#ccc; font-size:12px; text-align:center;}
.LD_cnt_cnt {text-align:center;}
.LD_cnt_cnt sup {float:left;font-size:9px;line-height:20px;text-transform:uppercase;}

.LD_1 {text-align:center;}
.LD_1 h3 {font-weight:bold; margin:0; color:#cc4c4c;}
.LD_2 {font-size:12px; text-align:center;}
.LD_lctn {text-align:center; font-size:12px; text-transform:uppercase; margin-bottom:3px !important; font-weight:bold;}
.LD_7 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_7:after {content:'•';padding:0 4px;}
.LD_8 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_8:after {content:'•';padding:0 4px;}
.LD_9 {display:inline-block;}
.LD_3 {}
.LD_4 {}
.LD_5 {}
.LD_6 {}
.LD_10 {}
.LD_11 {font-size:12px;}
.LD_12 {}
.LD_13 {}
.LD_14 {}
.LD_15 {}
.LD_16 {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LDWrap">
  <div id="LDX"><h2>Custom Guitar Builders <span>Directory</span></h2></div>
  <div id="LDMen">
    <h4>Filter Results</h4>
<div id="LD_filters">
  <span>Country:</span>
  <select id="countryFilter">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
  <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
  <input id="customsFilter" type="checkbox" name="filt_customs" value="customs"><span>Custom Builders</span><br>
  <input id="originalsFilter" type="checkbox" name="filt_originals" value="originals"><span>Original Models</span><br>
    <input id="orderFilter" type="checkbox" name="filt_orders" value="orders"><span>Online Orders</span><br>
    </div> <!---filters--->
  </div>
  <div id="LDInf">
    <div id="show-data"></div>
    <div id="LD_scrl">Scroll Down</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding what I was trying to do here! I'm going to be combining your code with the other answer to populate the country list with unique countries based on the JSON fields - hopefully I don't get too much of a headache.

Comment: You're welcme! I didn't think of the unique countries filter (very clever of you).

Comment: `if (selector.length == 0) selector = ".LD_item_wrap"; else selector = ".LD_item_wrap" + selector;` could be replaced by just `selector = ".LD_item_wrap" + selector;`. Just notices it ;D.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to create dropdown of unique countries from the returned data. Not aiming for efficient way but does the job.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var uniqueElements = []

    function CheckIfExists(field) {
        var exists = false;
        $.each(uniqueElements, function (i2, field2) {
            if (field2.COUNTRY == field.COUNTRY) {
                exists = true;
                return true;
            };
        });
        return exists;
    }

    $.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/7g9yf.json", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, field) {
            if (!CheckIfExists(field)) {
                uniqueElements.push(field)
            }
        });
        $('select').empty();
        $('select').append($('<option>', {
                value : 'All',
                text : 'All'
            }))
        $.each(uniqueElements, function (i, item) {
            $('LD_filters select').append($('<option>', {
                    value : item.COUNTRY,
                    text : item.COUNTRY
                }));
        });

        /*
        Rest of your code
         */

    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for addressing this, I wasn't sure if anyone realized I was what I was trying to do after that other guy's comments on my original post. I'm going to try to work yours and the other answer into one frankenstein-type thing.